# Including drawer in all activities xml and calling them when clicked

Tags: java, android, xml, android-intent, navigation-drawer

I am working on an Android project in which I am using drawer for showing some always used activities. I have made sure that the activities dont need any special data, and can be started once logged in. But I dont know how to include the drawer in all XML files where I have my activities. I cannot find any good reference.

Also, When I do that, how can i start the activity instead of using fragments. So, for example, below is an example of my RestaurantLists xml file and displaying users xml file, where and how can I include the drawer there. Thanks.

Sorry for the long code, I am using somewhere ListActivity, somewhere just Activity, then baseadapter, I want to add drawer in all. Thats why. Thank you.

restos.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
</ListView>
```

displayUserList.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/usersdisplaylist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        >
    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I am using an adapter for displaying users, here is the adapter code and subsequent xml.  Please note, my question remains the same, how to include drawer in all XML files, so it is displayed.

```
public class UserAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    public UserAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
        activity = a;
        data = d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return data.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (convertView == null)
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.userprofiles, null);

        TextView username = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.userName);
        ImageView userImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.userImage);
        HashMap<String, String> usersList = new HashMap<>();
        usersList = data.get(position);
        username.setText(usersList.get(OtherUsers.firstName));
        byte [] encodeByte=usersList.get(OtherUsers.userImage).getBytes();
        Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encodeByte, 0, encodeByte.length);
        userImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        return view;
    }
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/userImage"
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:contentDescription="userPhoto" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/userName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

As you can see in the code below, i have commented out the code where I must start fragments. Shall I just start an Intent there, and then close the drawer?

Here is my code for displayView :

```
public class DrawerLoader extends Activity {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    // slide menu items
    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

    private ArrayList<DrawerModel> navDrawerItems;
    private DrawerListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.drawerlayout);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);
        navMenuIcons = getResources()
                .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);
        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<DrawerModel>();

        navDrawerItems.add(new DrawerModel(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
        // Find People
        navDrawerItems.add(new DrawerModel(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
        // Photos
        navDrawerItems.add(new DrawerModel(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
        // Communities, Will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new DrawerModel(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1), true, "22"));
        // Pages
        navDrawerItems.add(new DrawerModel(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
        // What's hot, We  will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new DrawerModel(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1), true, "50+"));

        // Recycle the typed array
        navMenuIcons.recycle();

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new DrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
                R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
            displayView(0);
        }


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action bar actions click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
     * */
    private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
              //  fragment = new HomeFragment();
                break;
            case 1:
                //   fragment = new FindPeopleFragment();
                break;
            case 2:
                //   fragment = new PhotosFragment();
                break;
            case 3:
                // fragment = new CommunityFragment();
                break;
            case 4:
                //  fragment = new PagesFragment();
                break;
            case 5:
                //  fragment = new WhatsHotFragment();
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    /* *
     * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }


    /**
     * Slide menu item click listener
     * */
    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            // TODO DisplayView guy
        //    displayView(position);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: you could host a single activity with drawer and add fragments into that activity, so in every page you will get the drawer layout, thus less redundant code

Comment: @GeorgeThomas That would take a major renovation for my existing code-base, which I am not willing to do now because of time constraints. Can you tell me how I can add it in all xml's? Thank you.

Comment: @GeorgeThomas Also, as this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19451715/same-navigation-drawer-in-different-activities  says, Having just one Activity can be a daunting task for any fairly complex app. Using Activities gives you a lot of free things from the system - so it is a valid point how to use multiple Activities. I can't imagine one Activity handling communication between any number of fragment combinations - it's just not gonna work . That's a comment by guy named slott.