# Is it possible to create subsequently a Navigation Drawer in Android?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I'm working on my App about 6 Months.

I don't know if I misread it but, is it possible to create and add a Navigation Drawer when I have different Activities?

How my App works:

SplashScreen -> LogInScreen -> Activity 1(`ListView`) -> Activity 2 (after click on `ListView` item) -> ... and so on.

Is it possible to add now a `Navigation Drawer`? I read something that you can add a `Navigation Drawer` only if you don't switch between Activities is that right?

I want a Navigation that looks on every `Activity` different. Is it possible or it can only have one layout?

I hope my problem is clearly explained.

Kind Regards

Comment: Yes, you can add a different Navigation Drawer to every Activity.

Comment: All right. Thank you for your comment!

Answer (score 1):

All your other **Activities** should extend The **MainActivity** which contains the **navigationView** .

helphuf links : [Same Navigation Drawer in different Activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19451715/same-navigation-drawer-in-different-activities) , [Android: Navigation-Drawer on all activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28678151/android-navigation-drawer-on-all-activities)

Comment: This looks helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. I suggest following option to use navigation drawer in all Activities of App.

You have a two option :

1) Use Fragment instead of Activity and put navigation drawer to First Activity.
for Example : http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

2) Create One layout for navigation-drawer and include it to all layout of your Activities using "" tag in xml Like this link : [navigation drawer layout with include layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24613154/navigation-drawer-layout-with-include-layout)

for Example : [Same Navigation Drawer in different Activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19451715/same-navigation-drawer-in-different-activities)

Comment: I want to add DIFFERENT layouts on every Activity. But thank you

Comment: yes u can use different layouts and add navigation drawer layout in all layouts using <include> tag in xml
Like this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24613154/navigation-drawer-layout-with-include-layout